# Swift Assign two values to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

Is it possible to assign two values to a cell in a UITableView?

I have a json file that is structured like this:

```
{
   "band": [
      "Name": "The Kooks",
      "id": "1258"
  ]
}
```

I can get the label to display in the cell and pass it to a new view controller, but how do I also assign the **id** so that I can pass that too?

I am new to swift so please dont eat me.

## Edit 1:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell
    
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
    
    return cell
}
```

items is empty, so I get it like so:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, testurl, parameters: ["bandName": bandName])
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                if let value = response.result.value {
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    
                    for (_,bands) in json {
                      for (_,bname) in bands {
                           let bandName = bname["Name"].stringValue
                            
                            print(bandName)
                            
                            self.items.append(bandName)
                            
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                           
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            case .Failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
            
    }
```

Comment: please use String(format: "String%@%@",variables);

Comment: erm? care to explain?

Comment: You don't assign it to a cell.  You keep the ID in your model, then retrieve it by the selected cell's `indexPath` within `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: Do you mean you can pass name or id in the label in each cell? Please post your code in cellForRowAtIndexPath and didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @khuong291 The cell shows the name, but I want to pass the id to a new view.

Comment: @PetahChristian I load the data dynamically into the table using alamofire. how would you suggest I do this?

Comment: So in didSelectRowAtIndexPath you just send the id base on it's name. It will be easy if you upload your code here.

Comment: Please show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to explain where your cell gets its data.

Comment: @PetahChristian see edit.

Comment: The id is in JSON. At the moment it isnt stored as I couldnt find a way to add it to the UItableView Cell

Comment: Please update your question once you've written code to extract it from JSON, and stored it.  Hint: Setup a `band` struct to hold `name` and `id` so you're not using a different array for each field.

Comment: @JamesG - I guess from your question that you want to connect the `id` to its corresponding cell to use it further on its click event. So you can make a custom cell and make a `peorperty` for `dictionary` and assign it to cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. `cell.info = self.items[indexPath.row]`.

Answer (score 1):

you should not add every value in bname Dictionary to self.items. 
Try add bname to self.items,code:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, testurl, parameters: ["bandName": bandName])
    .responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)

                for (_,bands) in json {
                  for (_,bname) in bands {

                        self.items.append(bname)

                        self.tableView.reloadData()

                    }
                }

            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }

}
```

and  in cellForRowAtIndexPath use it:
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

```
    let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell
    if let dic = self.items[indexPath.row] as? NSDictionary{
        if let id = dic["id"] as? String{
            cell.idLabel.text = id
        }
        if let name = dic["Name"] as? String{
            cell.nameLabel.text = name
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: cell.idLabel: Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'idLabel'

Comment: idLabel & nameLabel is just my example, you can show it: 
cell.textLabel?.text  = "\(id) & \(name)"

Answer (score 0):

Create class or model with these properties and  assign values in objects keep object in NSarray that works as datasource get object from datasource using selected indexpath and pass object to your new  viewcontroller using prepareForSegue.

Comment: No, and this is Objective-C not swift.